# Linking to duplicate that has bad accepted answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

(this has probably been asked before but search isn't bringing it up)

Someone asks a new question. It's a dupe but the original question has a bad accepted answer (an answer with objectively bad patterns, API usage, etc..). The original question does have a good answer but it's buried down the page and it would probably not be clear to someone with less experience why the bad answer is bad. Of course I can downvote the bad answer and upvote the good answer which I do but my one vote is not enough. I can also add a comment under the bad answer pointing out why it's bad but comments are often ignored by the questioner.

So the question is: Should I still mark the new question as a dupe knowing the odds are the questioner will be mislead into a bad answer?

Off the top of my head

- Don't vote close as dupe. Put a good answer on the new question
- Vote to close as dupe. Add comment under new question that accepted answer at the time of the comment is a bad answer and link to one of the good answers.
- Vote to close as dupe and do nothing. Assume the developer will read all the answers and figure out which one has best practices.
- Vote to close as dupe. Edit accepted answer removing bad practices (big changes required would basically no longer be the original answerer's answer)
- Other?

Note: if the original question doesn't have a good answer yet I can leave a new one but the problem remains that marking as dupe will lead many devs to the bad answer.

Comment: My vote goes to option one. We shouldn't dupe close just for the sake of dupe closing, you do it when it makes sense. You could also vote to close as dupe the question with the bad answer (and put a nice fat downvote on the bad answer, of course). All roads should lead to the better answer.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the good answer **is** in the duplicate target, but not accepted and somewhere down the list. I would go with 2. The only way I see for not closing would be to duplicate the good answer which is never a good idea.